# How do I set frame alignment?

Tags: html, css

How to set my frames in html as shown in diagram below? How to create rows in frame-set columns? Is CSS needed here?

```
<html>

 <frameset cols="25%,*">
 <frame src="myframe1.htm">
 <frame src="myframe2.htm">
 <frame src="myframe3.htm">
 </frameset>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Just to let you know, in case you don't: frames have been [deprecated and are no longer supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp)

Comment: What is alternative for it? Divs?

Comment: If you want to load an external file in, [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) with a bit of CSS will behave very similarly. Otherwise, you can make this layout with `<div>s`, `<table>s`, or really any element using inline-block or table-cell display, or with floating, or with positioning. It's really up to you how you want to do it, but `<frames>` are no longer supported, so I'd caution you not to use them going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need CSS for this. You can nest framesets and use the `rows` attribute, for example:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*">
  <frameset rows="*,*">
    <frame src="myframe1.htm">
    <frame src="myframe2.htm">
  </frameset>
  <frame src="myframe3.htm">
</frameset>
```